# Issues with .NET reflection

Tags: .net, reflection

Some issues with .NET reflection here ...

I have a scenario working with reflection in .NET: I have a class say, ClassA, which inherits a method from another class ClassA_Base. Both are in the same assembly. The method in question takes a parameter, an interface, IInterfaceA which is in another assembly. Now when I load up ClassA using reflection with the LoadFrom method that takes a path to the .dll, I get a MissingMethodException when I try to use the method and it does not show up when I break on the line in Visual Studio and view the base class methods. Interestingly, the base class also has some properties which return IInterfaceA and these ones show up! I'm wondering what the issue could be?

```
ClassA : ClassA_Base
{
}

ClassA_Base
{
   SomeMethod(IInterfaceA obj); //Doesn't show up
   IInterfaceA SomeProperty{ get; } //Shows up
}
```

This is implemented using F# but I believe the behaviour would be same with any other .NET language implementation.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the default `Type.GetMethod`, pass a `BindingFlags` value. Something like this:

```
typeof(ClassA).GetMethod("SomeMethod",
                         BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public,
                         null,
                         new Type[] { typeof(IInterfaceA) },
                         null);
```

Sorry I don't know how to translate it to F#.

Comment: Actually, what I'm doing is creating an instance first using:   assembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName, true, BindingFlags.Default, null, constructorparameters, null, null); How do I adapt your code for this scenario?

Comment: Well you need to have a `Type` object (I used `typeof`, but you will probably use `Assembly.GetType()`). You can use `GetMethod` to get the method, and I think you call `Invoke` on the method to execute it. You would pass the instance you got from `CreateInstance` to the `Invoke` method.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I got carried away by the abstraction of a dynamic invocation. I was doing the invocation through a dynamic method. Thanks. I'll try this out now. I'll change the implementation for the F# dynamic method and see what obtains.

Answer (score 0):

With reflection you are only retrieving the methods implemented on the current class. This means that for stuff in base classes don't show up. If you are wanting to find a method just look it up on the base class, you can then invoke it on the child.

The reason interface stuff shows up is that its still implemented on the concrete class. (rather than only being implemented on the base)